# touchesMoved detection doesn't work properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation

in my application I'm using touchesMoved method to detect swipe left/right.
when the user swipe to left and right continuously,image animation updates automatically.
I was able to detect swipe action but sometimes when I start to swipe left and right continuously,screen doesn't detect the touchmoved event.

in the swipe area I have placed one hidden button and few ImageViews for animations.
I want to know why it happens.please help me.

thank you.

code:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint newLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint oldLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];

    if(newLocation.x-oldLocation.x>0){
        swipe_direction = 1;
        //NSLog(@"left");
    }
    else{
        swipe_direction = 2;
        //NSLog(@"right");

    }

    if(swipe_direction == 1){
        //animate images
    }
    else if(swipe_direction == 2){
        //animate images
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`touchesMoved` Only detects on the empty part of the View. Therefore, it will not detect over the objects you used.

Place a SwipeGestureRecognizer over the view and use it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a SwipeGestureRecognizer instead of the touchesMoved?

Check the [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)